# SQL string replace based on WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a memo field which may contain & and the HTML equivalent &. I need to write a script to ensure that all instances of ampersand are the HTML equivalent. Have the below script but the WHERE clause does not seem to factor the individual instances (strings) of & in the memo field, just the field as a whole... Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Thanks.

```
 UPDATE 
    STOCKMEM
 SET 
    INETFDESC = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(INETFDESC as NVarchar(MAX)),'&','&amp;') AS NText)
 WHERE 
    INETFDESC LIKE '%&%' 
    AND INETFDESC NOT LIKE '%&amp;%'
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"the `WHERE` clause does not seem to factor the individual instances of `&`"*?  Can you show some sample data?

Comment: Because there are hundreds of thousands of rows and this is a memo field, looking have the where process only strings which need updating... so only instances where & is proceeded by "amp;" -- does that help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
 UPDATE STOCKMEM
 SET INETFDESC = CAST(
                      REPLACE(
                              REPLACE(
                                      CAST(INETFDESC as NVarchar(MAX))
                              ,'&amp;','&')
                      , '&', ,'&amp;')AS NText)
 WHERE INETFDESC LIKE '%&[^amp;]%'
```

The first replace will change `&amp;` to `&`, and the second will replace all `&` back to `&amp;`.

BTW, Please note that `NText` data type is [**depricated**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) and you should convert it to `nvarchar(max)`.
From MSDN:

> **IMPORTANT!**  **ntext**, **text**, and **image** data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use **nvarchar(max)**, **varchar(max)**, and **varbinary(max)** instead.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Zohar! With the WHERE LIKE processing all instances of &, not just those needing updating, are there any efficiencies to be gained by adjusting that? This memo field has hundreds of thousands of rows. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Zohar, look forward to your feedback.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Now the where clause will not select columns that only have `&amp;`

Comment: Zohar, this is perfect -- thanks so much for sharing your expertise.

Comment: Hi again Zohar, we ran into an issue where there could potentially be other special HTML characters that begin with the “&” (i.e. &mdash; &quot; etc)... so we need to make sure that we don't convert those & to the &amp; otherwise we end up converting something like &mdash; to &amp;mdash; ... that said, the longest HTML tag which can start with & seems to be six characters, so &_ _ _ _ _ _; ... do you have any ideas on updating the where clause so that it does not update any & which are proceeded with a ";" in the next 1-7 characters after the &? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: That's a harder problem... It's been forever since I've used HTML, How mamy of these entities are there?

Comment: There's many. This is a compressive list: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm.  But if there was a way to skip any & in where clause which had a ";" in position 4, 5, 6, or 7 after the & that may consider all scenarios.

Comment: Thge problem is that the where clause will not help here, since nothing is stopping the content from containing both `&` and `&quot;` or any other html entity. Best way to handle such things is outside of sql using a programming language.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish the same thing by this:

```
 UPDATE STOCKMEM
 SET INETFDESC = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),(REPLACE(REPLACE(INETFDESC, '&amp;', '&'), '&', '&amp;')))
WHERE INETFDESC LIKE '%&%'
```